# Making Bootstrap table-striped table transparent

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I want to make the table transparent and I want to see the background image through the table list which is striped with different colors.

I have tried the following but it didn't work.

```
<style> #loading {
    position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: url('http://www.jettools.com/images/animated_spinner.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
</style>    
<div id="loading"></div>        
             <table  style="background: transparent !important;">        
                <thead>
                <th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th>
                </thead>                    
                <tbody style="background: transparent !important;" >                    
                <tr>                        
                    <td title="">                   
                    </td>                           
                    <td title="" 
                    </td>                       
                    <td title="">                       
                    </td>                       
                    <td title="">        
                    </td>                           
                </tr>                           
                </tfoot>  </tfoot>        
                </tbody>                            
            </table>
```

Comment: can you post more of your code as well as a fiddle?

Comment: I have edited it for you Steve.